# How to implement refres token to youtube API

Tags: python, youtube-api, google-oauth, google-api-python-client, refresh-token

I want to upload a video with youtube API and always I get a message from google to terminal check this link to validate your application I read that I can use for it a refresh token function I found some on the internet but it is not working. I do not know why but I have done all steps before this so for every help I will be happy. Thanks

function:

```
import pickle
import os
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import Flow, InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload, MediaIoBaseDownload
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
import datetime


def Create_Service(client_secret_file, api_name, api_version, *scopes):
    print(client_secret_file, api_name, api_version, scopes, sep='-')
    CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = client_secret_file
    API_SERVICE_NAME = api_name
    API_VERSION = api_version
    SCOPES = [scope for scope in scopes[0]]
    print(SCOPES)

    cred = None

    pickle_file = f'token_{API_SERVICE_NAME}_{API_VERSION}.pickle'
    # print(pickle_file)

    if os.path.exists(pickle_file):
        with open(pickle_file, 'rb') as token:
            cred = pickle.load(token)

    if not cred or not cred.valid:
        if cred and cred.expired and cred.refresh_token:
            cred.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
            cred = flow.run_console()

        with open(pickle_file, 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(cred, token)

    try:
        service = build(API_SERVICE_NAME, API_VERSION, credentials=cred)
        print(API_SERVICE_NAME, 'service created successfully')
        return service
    except Exception as e:
        print('Unable to connect.')
        print(e)
        return None

def convert_to_RFC_datetime(year=1900, month=1, day=1, hour=0, minute=0):
    dt = datetime.datetime(year, month, day, hour, minute, 0).isoformat() + 'Z'
    return dt
```

and this is my code:

```
import argparse
import http.client
import httplib2
import os
import random
import time
import datetime

import google.oauth2.credentials
import google_auth_oauthlib.flow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow

httplib2.RETRIES = 1

MAX_RETRIES = 10

RETRIABLE_EXCEPTIONS = (httplib2.HttpLib2Error, IOError, http.client.NotConnected,
  http.client.IncompleteRead, http.client.ImproperConnectionState,
  http.client.CannotSendRequest, http.client.CannotSendHeader,
  http.client.ResponseNotReady, http.client.BadStatusLine)

RETRIABLE_STATUS_CODES = [500, 502, 503, 504]

CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE = 'youtube_client.json'


SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload']
API_SERVICE_NAME = 'youtube'
API_VERSION = 'v3'

VALID_PRIVACY_STATUSES = ('public', 'private', 'unlisted')

upload_date_time = datetime.datetime(2022, 12, 25, 12, 30, 0).isoformat() + '.000Z'
request_body = {
    'snippet': {
        'categoryI': 10,
        'title': 'best music on the youtube | happy mood mix | AMP',
        'description': "test",
        'tags': ['Travel', 'video test', 'Travel Tips']
    },
    'status': {
        'privacyStatus': 'private',
        'publishAt': upload_date_time,
        'selfDeclaredMadeForKids': False, 
    },
    'notifySubscribers': False
}



def get_authenticated_service():
  flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE, SCOPES)
  credentials = flow.run_console()
  return build(API_SERVICE_NAME, API_VERSION, credentials = credentials)

def initialize_upload(youtube,body,file):

  
  insert_request = youtube.videos().insert(
    part='snippet,status',
    body=body,
    media_body=MediaFileUpload(file, chunksize=-1, resumable=True))
  response = resumable_upload(insert_request)
  return response
  
def resumable_upload(request):
  response = None
  error = None
  retry = 0
  while response is None:
    try:
      print('Uploading file...')
      status, response = request.next_chunk()
      if response is not None:
        if 'id' in response:
          print('Video id "%s" was successfully uploaded.' % response['id'])
        else:
          exit('The upload failed with an unexpected response: %s' % response)
    except HttpError as e:
      if e.resp.status in RETRIABLE_STATUS_CODES:
        error = 'A retriable HTTP error %d occurred:\n%s' % (e.resp.status,
                                                             e.content)
      else:
        raise
    except RETRIABLE_EXCEPTIONS as e:
      error = 'A retriable error occurred: %s' % e

    if error is not None:
      print(error)
      retry += 1
      if retry > MAX_RETRIES:
        exit('No longer attempting to retry.')

      max_sleep = 2 ** retry
      sleep_seconds = random.random() * max_sleep
      print('Sleeping %f seconds and then retrying...' % sleep_seconds)
      time.sleep(sleep_seconds)
  return response['id']


if __name__ == '__main__':

  youtube = get_authenticated_service()

  try:
    response = initialize_upload(youtube,request_body,"output.mp4" )
  except HttpError as e:
    print('An HTTP error %d occurred:\n%s' % (e.resp.status, e.content))

  youtube.thumbnails().set(
    videoId=response.get('id'),
    media_body=MediaFileUpload('thumbnail.png')
  ).execute()
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to let the client library do most of the work for you.

In the code below you will find that the first time it us token.json file is created

This file will contain

1. the access token from the user
2. the refresh token
3. the client id used to create it
4. the client used to create it
5. what scopes it authorizes.

## token.json

```
{
  "token": "[redacted]",
  "refresh_token": "[redacted]",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "client_id": "[redacted]",
  "client_secret": "[redacted]",
  "scopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube"
  ],
  "expiry": "2022-08-15T13:05:53.162649Z"
}
```

Every time it is run it will check if this file exists if it does exist then it will attempt to load the credentials  using from_authorized_user_file.  If it does not exist then access will be requested of the user.

## code

```
#   To install the Google client library for Python, run the following command:
#   pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client google-auth-httplib2 google-auth-oauthlib


from __future__ import print_function

import os.path

from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube']

def main():

    """Shows basic usage of the YouTube v3 API.
    Prints the names and ids of the first 10 files the user has access to.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        try:
            creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
            creds.refresh(Request())
        except google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError as error:
            # if refresh token fails, reset creds to none.
            creds = None
            print(f'Refresh token expired requesting authorization again: {error}')
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'C:\YouTube\dev\credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())

    try:
        service = build('youtube', 'v3', credentials=creds)

        # Call the YouTube v3 API
        results = service.videos().list(
            part='snippet',
            chart='mostPopular',
            fields="nextPageToken, items").execute()
        items = results.get('items', [])

        if not items:
            print('No videos found.')
            return
        print('Videos:')
        for item in items:
            print(u'{0} ({1})'.format(item['id'], item['snippet']['title']))
    except HttpError as error:
        # TODO(developer) - Handle errors from drive API.
        print(f'An error occurred: {error}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

## note

1. access tokens are valid for one hour the code will refresh it as needed.
2. refresh tokens for applications currently in testing will be good for seven days.  At which point you will need to delete the token json file and authorize the application again.
3. once your application is in production the refresh tokens will no longer expire